# How does whereClause work in public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sql-delete

So I'm trying to delete a Row from my database by passing the id of the specified row and I've found some code online but I really don't know how it works. It uses the whereClause argument in  the db.delete method of SQLiteDatabase. Does anyone get the logic behind it? What getWhereClause does exactly?

```
 //the delete method in my database class
 public void deleteRow(String compareColumn, String compareValue) {
    // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
    try {
        String whereClause = getWhereClause(compareColumn, compareValue);
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, null);
        //db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DB DELETE ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  //the method that returns whereClause
private String getWhereClause(String compareColumn, String compareValue) {
    String whereClause = null;
    if (compareColumn == null || compareColumn == "") { }
    else if (compareValue == null || compareColumn == "") { }
    else { whereClause = compareColumn + "=\"" + compareValue + "\""; }
    return whereClause;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete()` uses the passed in `whereClause` to construct an SQL statement like `DELETE FROM <tablename> WHERE <whereClause>`. In case the passed in `whereClause` is `null`, the `WHERE <whereClause>` is omitted and all rows are deleted.

Your `getWhereClause()` constructs an expression that can be used as `whereClause`, comparing a column to a specified string literal value, like `foo="bar"`. If either one is null or empty, a null `whereClause` is returned so all rows are matched.

Answer (score 1):

It just checks that arguments are non-`null`/non-empty and returns the statement for the `WHERE` condition like the following: `message = "Superman"`. So the result query will be like: `DELETE FROM myTable WHERE message = "Superman"`

BTW, since it's string literal, it's better to use single quotes instead of double quotes, like so `whereClause = compareColumn + "='" + compareValue + "'"`

Answer (score 1):

To simply explain, It takes two arguments

1.Column name

2.Column value

and creates a `String` literal and return it. Say for example '**student_id=100**', where column name is `student_id` and column_value is `100`. When any of the two arguments are null, then it returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

The method `deleteRow()` gets the column (something like "Name") and the value (something like "Lukas"):

```
public void deleteRow(String compareColumn, String compareValue)
```

The String variable `whereClause` uses the `getWhereClause(column, value)`- method to formate the both String variables in a SQL where clause like (`WHERE name LIKE "Lukas"`).

Now the `.delete()` method of the Object `db` takes the variable `whereClause` as an argument and executes the delete query.